# go - software panics for concurrent access despite being handled by mutexes

Tags: dictionary, go, concurrency, mutex

i have a map that is being read and written by 3 goroutines constantly, the program always ends up with a "fatal error: concurrent map iteration and map write" despite me setting up the mutex to protect it, I know I could use sync.Map or I could sync with a channel but I'd really like to understand what I am doing wrong. this is the code:

```
//book.go
type OrderbookMap map[float64]float64

type Orderbook struct {
    Bids     OrderbookMap
    Asks     OrderbookMap
    Symbol   string
    IsInit   bool
    UpdateId int
    mu sync.Mutex
}

func (book *Orderbook) Init() {

    book.mu.Lock()
    defer book.mu.Unlock()

    if book.IsInit {
        return
    }
    book.Asks = make(OrderbookMap)
    book.Bids = make(OrderbookMap)
    book.IsInit = true
}
//functions with mutexes
func DelBid2(b *Orderbook, price float64) {
    b.mu.Lock()
    defer b.mu.Unlock()
    if _, ok := b.Bids[price]; ok {
        delete(b.Bids, price)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("VALUE NOT FOUND %v\n", price)
    }
}


func AddBid2(b *Orderbook, price float64, qty float64) {
    b.mu.Lock()
    defer b.mu.Unlock()
    b.Bids[price] = qty
}


func GetBids2(b *Orderbook) OrderbookMap {
    b.mu.Lock()
    defer b.mu.Unlock()
    return b.Bids
}

//TesterFile.go
func TestBookRace(t *testing.T) {
    var B Orderbook
    B.Init()
    //add
    go func() {
        for {
            b, q := rFloat(), rFloat()
            AddBid2(&B, b, q)
            fmt.Printf("ADD %v NEW: %v\n", b, GetBids2(&B))
        }
    }()
    //del
    go func() {
        for {
            b := rFloat()

            DelBid2(&B, b)
            fmt.Printf("DEL %v NEW: %v\n", b, GetBids2(&B))
        }
    }()
    //read
    go func() {
        for {
            fmt.Printf("READ %v\n", GetBids2(&B))
        }
    }()


    for { time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)}
}
```

Comment: Your `GetBids2` function returns an unsynchronized reference when that function returns. So the runtime is able to detect this and panic.

Comment: You're not protecting the reads with a lock, you're passing the maps into `fmt.Printf`

Comment: I understood, I'll copy it to another temporary variable.